# C# WPF - Binding TextBlock Alignment to ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, textbox, alignment, textblock

I have ListView with dynamic TextBox. It looks like this.

[image]

What i want is, to create two TextBlock over the TextBoxList left and right. Is there a way to bind the alignment of my TextBlock to the TextBox at the top. I want this because my TextBoxList is dynamic, this means my two TextBoxLists could be more right or more down.

I hope you Guys have some ideas, greetings!

Comment: Can you provide us some code.how you create your view. If you use code behind or a template.

Comment: Yeah i need to have my TextBoxes in a ListView

Comment: What kind of "alignment" are you talking about?